# cakephp media plugin + jQuery Fileuploader plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, media, file-upload

**MY CASE:**

I'm working on a project on Cakephp, and i'm using david persson's media plugin + jquery Fileuploader plugin following [this tutorial](http://pixelcone.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-using-jquery-and-cakephp-media-plugin). and it works great.

The problem is that my case is a bit more complicated. I want the Attachment model (called Gallery in the tut) to belong to my **Posts model** and **User model**, and so I call the fileuploader in my posts' form and in my users' form.

**MY PROBLEM**

is that no file nor record is created after uploading from my posts' or users' form! any help on how to do that? any website i could take a look at?

I've tried different approaches, but i don't want this question to be neverending...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to give a proper answer without more information, but for it to work you would need a way of relating media to a post/user. Either as `hasMany` or `HABTM` relationship.

e.g a table `attachments_posts` with `id`, `attachment_id` and `post_id` or `user_id`

use `$this->ModelName->getLastInsertID();` after saving data (and uploading your file to get the ID(s) of the attachment and the user/post record.

You can then insert the `id` of the post/user and the id of the `attachment` in to the join table - and link it all together.